# Adding vertices where objects overlap (non Boolean?)

Tags: vertices, faces

I'm trying to make characters that kind of resemble tennis balls with happy faces. Basic Boolean methods end up removing part of the objects.

I want to have 2 objects overlap and Blender creates new vertices on the faces where the edges pass through. I don’t want anything removed by the Boolean process. I only want the vertices created so I can modify what I need afterwards on my own.

Take a sphere.
Put a cylinder through it.
Then create vertices on the sphere faces where the cylinder passes through. 
This marks where an eye will be. Repeat for the rest of the character.

[image: Ball face]

Comment: If you are speaking about faces ... you can use [_Knife Project_](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html), but isn't it more efficient to use image texture?

Comment: You could use the knife project tool with a circle as the cutting object for something like that. Quick tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Il40j3MiQ5M).

Comment: I’m using cone shapes so I can have perfect control over the symmetry, shapes, angle, size, and location of the objects. Knife Project requires an extreme level of skill to consistently align things perfectly. I make a cone and stick the cone through the ball and the top of the cone is centered in the exact center of the ball. I can type in the exact coordinates I want and rotate like a spotlight, so I never have to eyeball anything.

Answer (score 2):

*Sorry I didn't get the goal all of this ... your OP is about Cylinder, comment about a Cone ... probably I can't imagine the final product ....*

---

[Knife Project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html)

- Create your shape (smile) with origin in center of ball, vertices move above ball surface
- With smile object selected you can rotate around a ball as you like

[image]

- To get aligned view for projection - go to *View > Align View >* **Align View to Active**
  in this case *Top* <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>

[image]

- with <kbd>Shift</kbd> select Ball, switch to edit and search for Knife Project operator

Result - perfectly aligned cut "smile" according to your object orientation by single click.

[image]